# Printing out stack gives weird positioning of

Tags: c, stack, memory-address

I'm currently trying to understand string formatting vulnerabilities in C, but to get there, I have to understand some weird (at least for me) behaviour of the memory stack.

I have a program

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[200];
  char key[] = "secret";

  printf("Location of key: %p\n", key);
  printf("Location of buffer: %p\n", &buffer);

  strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
  printf(buffer);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

which I call with

```
./form AAAA.BBBE.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
```

What I would expect is to get something like

... .41414141.42424245. ...

but I get

... .41414141.4242422e.30252e45. ... (there is some character in between B and E).

What is happening here?

I disabled ASLR and stack protection and compile it with -m32 flag.

Comment: Have you disabled optimizations as well?

Comment: I also think that looking at assembly output (`-S` key in gcc) would provide some valuable insight.

Comment: What compiler and OS do you use? For example, System V ABI (used on 64-bit Linux) passes some arguments through registers, not stack.

Comment: I'm on Fedora 64-bit (therefor the -m32 flag), using gcc 6.3.1. Which other optimizations are there to disable?

Comment: Compiler optimizations: `-O0` (may be the default, actually). Would you mind elaborating a little on why are you expecting the string you mentioned? E.g. I do not see that your expected output ever mentions code of the dot  - `2e`.

Comment: A very interesting read by the way is `smashing the stack for fun and profit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your output is just fine. x86 is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - least significant byte of a number has smaller address in memory, so 1000 (`0x3E8`) is stored as `E8 03`, not `03 E8` (that would be big-endian).

Let's assume that the compiler passes all arguments to `printf` through stack and variadic arguments are expected to be laid on the stack from its top to its end (on x86 that means "from lower addresses to higher addresses").

So, before calling `printf` our stack would like like this:

```
<return address><something>AAAA.BBBE.%08x.%<something>
^ - head of the stack
```

Or, if we spell each byte in hex:

```
<return address><something>414141412e424242452e253038782e25<something>
^ - head of the stack      A A A A . B B B E . % 0 8 x . %
```

Then you ask `printf` to take a lot of unsigned `int`s from the stack (32-bit, presumably) and print them in hexadecimal, separated by dots. It skips `<return address>` and some other details of stack frame and starts from some random point in the stack before `buffer` (because `buffer` is in parent's stack frame). Suppose that at some point it takes the following chunk as 4-byte `int`:

```
<return address><something>414141412e424242452e253038782e25<something>
^ - head of the stack      A A A A . B B B E . % 0 8 x . %
                             ^^^^^^^^
```

That is, our int is represented in memory with four bytes. Their values are, starting from the byte with the smallest address: `41 41 41 2e`. As x86 is a little-endian, `2e` is the most significant byte, which means this sequence is interpreted as `0x2e414141` and printed as such.

Now, if we look at your output:

```
41414141.4242422e.30252e45
```

We see that there are three `int`s: `0x41414141` (stored as `41 41 41 41` in memory), `0x4242422e` (stored as `2e 42 42 42` in memory because the least significant byte has the smallest address) and `0x30252e45` (stored as `45 2e 25 30` in memory). That is, in that case `printf` read the following bytes:

```
number one |number two |number three|
41 41 41 41|2e 42 42 42|45 2e 25 30 |
A  A  A  A |.  B  B  B |E  .  %  0  |
```

Which looks perfectly correct to me - it's beginning of `buffer` as expected.

Comment: Oh well, that makes a lot of sense. I really have a hard time wrapping my head around the little endian... makes thing more complicated then they should be ^^;;

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially what you're outputting with the `%08x` formats, and you're on a little-endian machine:

```
41 41 41 41 2e 42 42 42 45 2e 25 30 38 78 2e 25 30 38 78 2e 25 30 38 78 2e
```

- The first is all `41`s, and they get flipped to be all `41`s.
- The next four bytes are `2e424242`, which become `4242422e`.
- Then, `452e2530` becomes `30252e45`.

It's easier to figure this out if you look at `buffer` in a memory window in your debugger.

By the way, you can print the address of buffer like this (without the &):

```
printf("Location of buffer: %p\n", buffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're passing `AAAA.BBBE.%08x...` to printf which is the format specifier. So printf expects an additional `unsigned integer` argument for every `%08x`. But you don't provide any, the behaviour will be undefined.

You can read in the [C Draft Standard (n1256)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> If  there  are  insufficient  arguments  for  the  format,  the  behavior  is undefined.

You're getting hexadecimal output from anywhere which is in your case from the stack.

Comment: That's exactly the point of the author: he's learning about stack vulnerabilities, which invoke undefined behavior "by design".

Comment: @yeputons: But his result is not wrong he got any hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: This question is not about "general abstract C" in which the compiler is allowed to format hard drive in case of undefined behavior. The question is about a specific class of vulnerabilities which exploit typical "undefined" behavior which happens in general compilers in such situations. In that case, as author assumes, this behavior does not correspond to "typical" undefined behavior.